# Custom Schema Types

Tags: neo4j, structr

I'm working through the "Building Graph-Based Web Applications With Structr 1.0" video and I've hit a bump when I get to adding a custom schema type.

First - it lists the new type "extends" a bunch of types - so far I haven't found what that means, so I've left it as an AbstractNode.

Next - when I add the type and then go to the "Data" tab, the new type isn't in the tab list - if I click on "Schema Node" the new types are listed there like so:

[image]

I checked the .config file to see if the schema service is setup to  start, and it's in the list:

```
configured.services = NodeService AgentService CronService SchemaService LogService HttpService FtpService CloudService
```

There's no "Show Custom types" option on my "Data" tab - it looks like this:
[image]

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You might need to enable the custom types display by unchecking the "Show selected tabs only" and then checking "Custom types".

Comment: See also https://support.structr.com/article/210 and https://support.structr.com/article/274.

Comment: I'm running the Linux binary, and I'm not seeing any check boxes - I've added a screen cap to the question. None of the tabs have any check-box options like you're describing. If you look at article210, there's no check box on that page either.

Comment: My version doesn't have any check boxes on the individual tabs like article210 has - am I running an older version?

Comment: Probably yes. The build date and ID are displayed in the upper right corner. It is recommended to use the latest snapshot version from here: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/structr/structr-ui/2.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: I'll give that a shot - thought if the most recent version is recommended, then why are the official downloads based on older versions?

Comment: I got 2.0 build 5403e working on Linux, and the new type is there now.

Comment: The recommended download on https://structr.org/download is always linked to the latest public snapshot.

Comment: You may want to double-check that then.

Answer (score 1):

Running 2.0 Build 5403 gave me the updated tabs in the Data area.